# VisualStateManager change background frame/pancakeview does not work

Tags: xamarin.forms

Problem

- Visual state manager does not kick in
- How do I change background of
  the selected frame?

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

[image]

I need to create an horizontal list with a set of frames that when selected change background color.

The obvious implementation would be a collectionView and that has a SelectedItem that would just work , so what is the problem with that?

Well if you have a pancakeView/frame with rounded corners in iOS you can see the grey background and its a bug  reported in xamarin forms.

So I decided to implement a bindableLayout, this works fine however I have tried all sorts but I cannot change the background color of the pancake/frame and a label on selection , below is what I have done

**MAIN PAGE**

```
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="LabelA" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Labelb" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
            <FlexLayout x:Name="Flex" 
                        Direction="Row" 
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                        Position="Relative" 
                        AlignItems="Start" 
                        FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                        JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Padding="8,0" FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start" >
                            <pancakeView:PancakeView x:Name="myPancake" 
                                                     Padding="20" 
                                                     Margin="5" 
                                                     CornerRadius="5" 
                                                     WidthRequest="60" 
                                                     HeightRequest="60" 
                                                     BackgroundColor="White" >
                                <pancakeView:PancakeView.Border>
                                    <pancakeView:Border Thickness="1" Color="Blue"  />
                                </pancakeView:PancakeView.Border>

                                <StackLayout >
                                    <Label x:Name="LabelA" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                           Text="{Binding Name }"
                                                           TextColor="Gray"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Labelb" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                                           TextColor="Gray" 
                                                           FontSize="12"
                                                           Text="SomeText Here" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <pancakeView:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped">

                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </pancakeView:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                            </pancakeView:PancakeView>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </FlexLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

**MAIN PAGE CODE BEHIND**

```
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace BlankApp2.Views
    {
        public partial class MainPage
        {
            string currentColorState = "Normal";
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                currentColorState = currentColorState == "Normal" ? "Focused" : "Normal";

                //below has errors since "myPancake, LabelA Labelb are not recognized WHY????

                //  VisualStateManager.GoToState(myPancake,_currentColorState);
                //  VisualStateManager.GoToState(LabelA, _currentColorState);
                // VisualStateManager.GoToState(Labelb, _currentColorState);
            }
        }
    }
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    namespace BlankApp2.ViewModels
    {
        public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
                : base(navigationService)
            {
                Title = "Main Page";
                Cities = GetCities();

            }
            private ObservableCollection<City> cities;
            public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
            {
                get => cities;
                set => SetProperty(ref cities, value);
            }
            private ObservableCollection<City> GetCities()
            {
                var list = new ObservableCollection<City>
                {
                    new City {Name = "London"},
                    new City {Name = "Rome"},
                    new City {Name = "New York"}
                };

                return list;
            }
        }
        public class City
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` your frame/pancakeviw(Here I'm testing with frame).

create a custom frame:

```
class MyFrame :Frame
{
    public bool IsFoucs { get; set; }
}
```

the page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyFrame">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LabelA" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Labelb" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Gray"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LabelA" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Labelb" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<FlexLayout x:Name="Flex" 
                    Direction="Row" 
                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                    Position="Relative" 
                    AlignItems="Start" 
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                    JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Padding="8,0" FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start" >
                <local:MyFrame x:Name="myPancake" 
                                                 Padding="20" 
                                                 Margin="5" 
                                                 CornerRadius="5" 
                                                 WidthRequest="60" 
                                                 HeightRequest="60" 
                                                 BorderColor="Blue"
                                                 BackgroundColor="White" >
           

                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label x:Name="LabelA" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                       Text="{Binding .}"
                                                       TextColor="Gray"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        </Label>
                        <Label x:Name="Labelb" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                                       TextColor="Gray" 
                                                       FontSize="12"
                                                       Text="SomeText Here" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <local:MyFrame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped">

                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </local:MyFrame.GestureRecognizers>
                </local:MyFrame>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

then in the page.cs:

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Flex.Children)
        {
            MyFrame frame = (MyFrame)item.FindByName("myPancake");
            frame.IsFoucs = false;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(frame, "Normal");
        }
        MyFrame myFrame = sender as MyFrame;
        myFrame.IsFoucs = !myFrame.IsFoucs;
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(myFrame, myFrame.IsFoucs ? "Focused" : "Normal");
    }
```

the effect is like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your time copied the code and partly works. For some reasons whatever you tap is selected and does not deselect the previous tapped frame. What happens is you tap on first one , that is fine, 2nd one tapping requires double tapping before it gets selected but the previous one does not get deselected.Obviously you do not get that behavior do you ?

Comment: I even tried with dataTriggers and I could not make it work.

Comment: @developer9969 It's my mistake,as i use the same `currentColorState` for each frame.You could check the update above,i create a custom frame and add a bool property to it.

Comment: Hi there , now double tapping is not required by still leaving all the other frames selected. is there a way to loop and deselect all frame before setting it. Does it work in your example? again thanks for your time

Comment: @developer9969 Do you mean single choice ?

Comment: @developer9969 Ok,please check the update( in `TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped` ) above.

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!! I wasted all day yesterday trying all sorts of thing like datatrigger  etc..I could not make it work. EXCELLENT!!!!